# Unable to create camel salesforce endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel, salesforce

I am trying to connect to salesforce using Apache Camel salesforce component.

Here is a very simple route I am trying to start:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("salesforce:event/Case__e")
            .to("mock:end");
}
```

When trying to start it I am getting an obvious error saying I did not specify a client id:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clientId must be specified
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:149) ~[camel-util-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.SalesforceLoginConfig.validate(SalesforceLoginConfig.java:238) ~[camel-salesforce-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
```

That makes perfectly sense as according to Camel docs clentId parameter must be specified. To address this I am specifying a `clientId` as below:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("salesforce:event/Case__e?clientId=xyz")
            .to("mock:end");
}
```

When trying to start the route this time I am getting a rather strange error complaining about `clientId` being an unknown parameter:

```
Failed to resolve endpoint: salesforce://event/Case__e?clientId=xyz due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint.
Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint.
Unknown parameters=[{clientId=xyz}]
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong and how should I address this.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to the fact that [`clientId` is a **component option**](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/salesforce-component.html#_component_option_clientId) so it must be configured at the component level while you try to configure it like it was a query parameter / an endpoint option which cannot work.

Depending on the runtime that you use, the way to configure a component may change but the idea remains the same.

For example, assuming that you use an `application.properties` to configure your application, the configuration of your salesforce component would look like this:

**In application.properties**

```
# Salesforce credentials
camel.component.salesforce.login-config.client-id=<Your Client ID>
camel.component.salesforce.login-config.client-secret=<Your Client Secret>
camel.component.salesforce.login-config.refresh-token=<Your Refresh Token>
...
```

Here is a salesforce example https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/main/examples/salesforce-consumer/

Comment: It seems like a good explanation for the behaviour I am experiencing. I need to test it tomorrow and come back. In the first place I was hitting this problem when trying to use https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/next/reference/connectors/camel-salesforce-source-kafka-source-connector.html. Being quite hard to change the connector config redeploy and test again I just made up a simple camel app and the issue was exactly the same.

Comment: I can confirm that moving those settings at component level fixed the issue so I accept the answer as being a valid one. 

It would be good if you could have an explanation about why when configuring `camel-salesforce-source-kafka-source-connector` with `camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.clientId=xyz` the clientId=xyz ends up in the endpoint URI and such it produces the above exception. Hard to believe this connector was never tested.

Comment: it is another another question, please avoid mixing subject by creating a new question